# does this request content via https?

Tags: apache2, protocols

If I am accessing a page via `https://mypage.com` if I load a script tag via `<script src="/js/myscript.js"></script>`

Is the above script called via http or https?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [URI RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-5.4) specifies this.  Relative references starting with `/` are relative to the scheme://host base.  So that relative reference is equivalent to `https://mypage.com/js/myscript.js`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that will be requested via HTTPS.

Answer (score 2):

yes since the SSL certificate is applied to the page in which you request the javascript. When you connect to HTTPS it means you open a new port, so you are no longer in HTTP at the point you request that .js file. Then it will be loaded via HTTPS